# Validating a CMS page

Tags: php, html, validation, dom, xhtml

I am forcing a CMS (Concrete5) page to parse xml with:

```
<? header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml'); ?>
```

The parser is stepping me through the errors...

In trying to find a better method, I have read about php tidy and DOM.  I seem to fail at getting either one to load the CMS output; instead, it seems I am just getting the top level file.

1. Is this where output buffering comes into play?
2. I have read where some complain about the accuracy of (html5) validators.  If you believe your code to be near xhtml compliant, is the effort better spent stepping through a browser's errors than to use one of these tools?

   Thanks.

Environment: Localhost setup on Ubuntu Linux, Apache2, php, mysql using the concret5 CMS.